# Perl regex replace first name last name with first name last initial

Tags: perl

I want to have the output of $var below to be John D

`my $var = "John Doe";`

I have tried 
`$var =~ s/(.+\b.).+\z],'\1.'//g;`

Comment: and what do you want if it is "Lester del Rey"?

Comment: Not really an issue here could simply be Lester D then

Answer (score 3):

Here's a general solution (feel free to swap in '\w' where I used '.', and add a \s where I used \s+)

```
my $var = "John Doe";
(my $fname, my $linitial) = $var =~ /(.*)\s+(.).*/
```

Then you have the values

```
$fname = 'John';
$linitial = 'D';
```

and you can do:

```
print "$fname $linitial";
```

to get

```
"John D"
```

EDIT
Until you do your next match, each of the capture parentheses creates a variable ($1 and $2, respectively), so the whole thing can be shortened a bit as follows:

```
my $var = "John Doe";
$var =~ /(.*)\s+(.).*/
print "$1 $2";
```

Comment: is there anyway to do this in one statement without creating new variables?

Comment: Yep! 
Perl has a (mostly) awesome penchant for auto-creating variables, which are perfectly suited for this sort of situation. I've updated my answer to include this shortened alternative

Answer (score 1):

To replace the last sequence of non-whitespace characters with just the initial character, you could write this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $var = "John Doe";

$var =~ s/(\S)\S*\s*$/$1/;

print $var;
```

**output**

```
John D
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string has ascii names this will work

```
$var =~ s/([a-zA-Z]+)\s([a-zA-Z]+)/$1." ".substr($2,0,1)/ge;
```

Comment: for some reason this just returns a 1 instead of John D

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = "John Doe";
s/^(\w+)\s+(\w)/$1 \u$2/ for $var;
```

Comment: This won't work, and just titlecases the second word, i.e. `John   van Doe` → `John Van Doe`.

Comment: I just wrote an anwer with a similar regex that explains how it works. You should then be able to understand why your regex doesn't show the requested behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex that solves this problem is the substitution

```
s/^\w+\s+\K(\w).*/\U$1/s
```

What does this do?

- `^ \w+ \s+` matches a word at the beginning of the string, plus whitespace towards the next word
- `\K` is the *keep* escape. It keeps the currently matched part outside of that substring that is considered “matched” by the regex engine. This avoids an extra capture group, and is practically a look-behind.
- `(\w)` matches and captures one “word” character. This is the leading character of the second word in the string.
- `.*` matches the rest of the string. I do this to overwrite any other names that may come: you stated that `Lester del Ray` should be transformed to `Lester D`, not `Lester D Ray` as a solution with `\w*` instead of the `.*` part would have done. The `/s` modifier is relevant for this, as it enables `.` to match every character including newlines (who knows what's inside the string?).
- The substitution uses the `\U` modifier to uppercase the rest of the string, which consists of the value of the capture.

Test:

```
$ perl -E'$_ = shift; s/^\w+\s+\K(\w).*/\U$1/s; say' "Lester del Ray"
Lester D
$ perl -E'$_ = shift; s/^\w+\s+\K(\w).*/\U$1/s; say' "John Doe"
John D
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might be a little more usable/reusable in the long run.

`$initial = sub { return substr shift, 0, 1 ; };`

make a get initial function

`$var =~ s/(\w)\s+(\w)/&$initial($1) &$initial($2)/sge;`

Then replace the first and second results using execute in the regex;

Comment: I can't use a sub routine for this case.